# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'list2' of 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error and can't figure out why?

I am new to REACT and so confused about basics and am obliged for the help from this group.

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'list2' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
SimpleList5
C:/Nusrat/react/material-ui/src/Testmap3.jsx:14
  11 |     <SimpleList5 list2={mylist} />
  12 | );
  13 | 
> 14 | const SimpleList5 = ({ list2 }) => (
     | ^  15 |     list2.map(item => (
  16 |         <li key={item}>{item}</li>
  17 |     ))
```

Code is:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Testmap3 = () => {

    //If we would use the List as child component in another
    //component, we could pass the list as props to it:

    const mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    const App = () => (
        <SimpleList5 list2={mylist} />
    );

    const SimpleList5 = ({ list2 }) => (
        list2.map(item => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))
    )

    return (
        <div>
            SimpleList5 : {SimpleList5()}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Testmap3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`list2` may not be defined yet when trying to map over it.

To fix this try changing adding  `list2.map(item => (` to `list2 && list2.length && list2.map(item => (`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `SimpleList5` method with no arguments, but inside of this function you expect object which has list2 property inside. You need to pass argument when calling the `SimpleList5` function

Answer (score 0):

You have the `App` component defined inside the scope of `Testmap3` which correctly renders the `SimpleList5` component. But in the retuned value of `Testmap3` you are just invoking the function like this `{SimpleList5()}` which is causing the error because there was no props passed to the `SimpleList5` component.

Either render the `App` component or directly render the `SimpleList5` component with the props.

```
// the return value of Testmap3 component should be
return (
     <div>
       <App/>
     </div>
)

// or

return (
   <div>
     <SimpleList5 list2={mylist}/>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SimpleList5` should be it's own component that accepts a prop and `TestMap3` should render that component.

Right now, `list2` is undefined because you are invoking the `SimpleList5` function *without passing in the list2*.

The quickest solution would be to pass in `myList`:

```js
return (
 <div>
  SimpleList5: { SimpleList5({list2: myList}) }
 </div>
)
```

That should work. However, passing `myList` to the function is redundant since you have access to that array throughout the component so you could just map through that array without calling `SimpleList5` at all.

To do this the "react" way or the typical react pattern by passing down props, you have to create a functional component for SimpleList5 and have your TestMap3 return it.

You do not need the "App" function. And you want to pull your `SimpleList5` out into it's own component like so

```js
const SimpleList5 = ({ list2 }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {list2.map(item => {
        return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default SimpleList5
```

A few things are happening here.

- The component is taking in a `prop` called `list2`
- We are destructuring that from our `props` object so we can directly access it by using `list2` instead of `props.list2` (which we would have to do if we did not destructure.
- We are returning that `<li>` element for each element in `list2`.

The empty HTML tags, `<> </>` represent a react fragment. We use this so we do not have to have an unnecessary `div` tag (important to know that a react component can only return one parent element).

Now, to use this and pass in that `myList` you have, rewrite the `TestMap3` component:

```js
const TestMap3 = () => {
  const mylist = ["a", "b", "c"];

  return (
    <div>
      SimpleList5: <SimpleList5 list2={myList} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestMap3;
```

Here, we are declaring the `myList` array then returning a `div` with the simple list rendered. The `<SimpleList5 list2={myList} />` passes the `myList` array to the prop `list2`. Whenever `TestMap3` renders, SimpleList5 will have the `myList` in the `list2` prop.

Comment: Whats the advantage of using  <> </>  react fragment versus a <div></div>?

Comment: SimpleList5a: { SimpleList5({ list2: mylist })}  works !!
Can you kindly explain the syntax since its new for me. Why : is used?

Comment: The advantage of using fragment is you will not have to render a bunch of `div` to the DOM. A fragment groups the elements together. Instead of having
`
<div>
  SimpleList5
  <div>
     <li></li>
   </div>
</div>
`

You could have the outer div and then the list. If for styling purposes you wanted the div, certainly you can replace the fragment with the div or a ul or whatever you need for styling.

Comment: The syntax: ({ list2: myList }) is simply passing your function an object. It is not special react syntax by any means. Only an object being passed to a function. An object has a key and a value. The key in this case is list2 and the value is myList. You can have many unique keys in an object. For instance, { list1: myList1, list2: myList, list3: myList3 } etc. The curly braces { } define the object, the colon : separates the key from the value.